# Use Cell Value in Shell Script

Tags: vba, excel

Please help!

I'm new to VBA and trying to incorporate a macro which will, preferably in the form of a button, open a file from a directory using Notepad. This is easy enough when I am specifying the name of the file beforehand, but what I would like to do is open whichever filename is specified in the active cell.

One column in my data is the filename from which the data in each row comes, minus the path, so is there a way I can say "open DIRECTORY\ACTIVE CELL VALUE"?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes".  There is a way to open a file like that.  And there are HUNDREDS of Google results on the correct syntax.  Stack Overflow is not designed to ask people to write code for you.  Instead, we evaluate existing code and provide fixes where code is broken.  I've voted to close this.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Sorry but I couldn't find it on Google - probably because I didn't know the correct search terms to describe my problem. I wasn't expecting someone to write my code for me, just point me in the right direction. Thanks very much to the helpful user below.

Comment: I'm sorry to be blunt but this question does fall outside the scope as defined in the help center.  Eventually, it will probably get closed which means the "helpful" user will lose the reputation he gained trying to be helpful.

Comment: Okay. I have read the help centre guidelines and I still don't see how my question was inappropriate. I'm glad there are people who are willing to give two minutes of their time to save me a massive headache and aren't solely out for reputation points. I obviously wouldn't post on (hostile, apparently) forum asking for help if I hadn't already tried to solve the problem myself using Google. Thanks for your help.

Comment: We all make mistakes huh

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much there already, you just need to pick up the value in the active cell. This will do it:

```
Sub OpenFileInDefaultApp()

' open a file in it's windows default application

Dim filepath As String
Dim shellApp As Object

filepath = "" ' PUT YOUR CONSTANT FILEPATH HERE
filepath = filepath & "/" & ActiveCell.Text ' THIS IS FOR THE FILE NAME IN THE CELL
Set shellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

shellApp.Open (filepath)
```

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you so much. The only thing I had to change was the forward slash to a backslash and it worked perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: I always get / and \ mixed up :) Glad to help.